# How can I use Symfony with a SELECT inside a WHERE clause? I got error

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, where-clause

I'm migrating Mysql SQL to Symfony project and I get a error from TLP when I execute the SQL. I guess problem is in the second SELECT inside the WHERE clause.

If I use the original SQL, and I use without symfony framework I have no problems. Furthermore, if I use the clause WHERE with "(vars.ns IN (SELECT...))" I get no errors, but SQL must not be like that.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT vars.dm, vars.ns, vars.mc, vars.ac, vars.sf, vars.cn, vars.mp, vars.ta, vars.mo, vars.mh, vars.pa, vars.sp, vars.so, vars.sh, vars.sn, vars.mm, vars.ms, vars.gs, vars.a1, vars.a2, vars.updated FROM BaseBundle:Vars vars WHERE (SELECT device.id FROM BaseBundle:Device device WHERE device.ns = vars.ns AND device.idUser IS NOT NULL AND device.idUser != '422' AND device.idUser != '819') AND vars.idDevice IS NOT NULL AND vars.updated > :time")->setParameter('time', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-31 days')));
    $historics = $query->getResult();
```

And I get this error:

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
  [Syntax Error] line 0, col 233: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'
```

This SQL must return 276 rows and it does, but not in symfony. Any idea about the issue?
Thank you so much,

UPDATE:
MYSQL ORIGINAL QUERY

```
SELECT 
vars.dm,
vars.ns,
vars.mc,
vars.ac,
vars.sf,
vars.cn,
vars.mp,
vars.ta,
vars.mo,
vars.mh,
vars.pa,
vars.sp,
vars.so,
vars.sh,
vars.sn,
vars.mm,
vars.ms,
vars.gs,
vars.a1,
vars.a2,
vars.updated
FROM
table_3.vars
WHERE
   (SELECT 
        device.id_user
    FROM
        table_3.device
    WHERE
        device.ns = vars.ns
            AND device.id_user IS NOT NULL
            AND device.id_user != '422'
            AND device.id_user != '819')
    AND vars.id_device IS NOT NULL
    AND vars.updated > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: You might miss a something like `WHERE vars.device_id IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: I do not see `IN` statement in your query, right now your query is incorrect indeed

Comment: Point is I dont have any relationship between vars table (vars.id) and device table. So, If I use vars.id the result is wrong. In MYSQL works fine without it. I update with Mysql query

Answer (score 0):

First of all Doctrine does not use SQL it uses DQL. DQL looks similar, but works a bit differently when you talk about properties and fields. While creating Doctrine Query you have to use property names rather than field names and entity which you are referring to must exist with such properties. Is your BaseBundle:Vars entity present? and does it have properties mentioned in query string? And how about device entity?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error

> Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

because doctrine tries to parse the subquery condition:

```
(SELECT device.id FROM BaseBundle:Device device WHERE device.ns = vars.ns AND device.idUser IS NOT NULL AND device.idUser != '422' AND device.idUser != '819')
```

and expects it to be a [Literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/literals.html)

That happens because no [comparison](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html) has been defined for the above condition and doctrine assumes that this should be a literal and when "sees" that it starts with "SELECT", it throws the error.

To overcome this, add a comparison (eg ***> 0***) to the condition:

```
(SELECT device.id FROM BaseBundle:Device device WHERE device.ns = vars.ns AND device.idUser IS NOT NULL AND device.idUser != '422' AND device.idUser != '819') > 0
```